# Share data between cards in Gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have an addon, there is a form with 5 inputs and a new form renders on the main form as a new card which sends and API data from the user input.

I want to send data back to main card from the new card once popped.

What is the best what to achieve it?

Comment: It's probably going to be better for you if you will store the common data in a commonly accessisble buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manage it with cache service.